# VSCode Extension - API

Tags: vscode-extensions, vscode-api

I am trying to include similar icons with buttons like next to Open Editor on my vscode extension (1st image). Not sure where to add them.

[image]

I have worked this far:

[image]

Can someone tell which API to deploy next?

Comment: See this for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65905635/how-to-add-toggle-menu-to-view-title-with-vscode-extension

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/76615668/11107541

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's in your `package.json` -> `contributes`, checkout [this doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.views), and [this example](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/tree-view-sample)

package.json, line#149-160

```
    "menus": {
        "commandPalette": [
            {
                "command": "ftpExplorer.revealResource"
            }
        ],
        "view/title": [
            {
                "command": "nodeDependencies.refreshEntry",
                "when": "view == nodeDependencies",
                "group": "navigation"
            },
```

package.json, line#67-74

```
    "commands": [
        {
            "command": "nodeDependencies.refreshEntry",
            "title": "Refresh",
            "icon": {
                "light": "resources/light/refresh.svg",
                "dark": "resources/dark/refresh.svg"
            }
```

you need a `view/title` entry which points to a `command` entry, the icon is in the command, it can be custom image or vscode's [codicon](https://microsoft.github.io/vscode-codicons/dist/codicon.html), you might want to read [this doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/icons-in-labels)