# How do I make my extension add a menu item to a context menu in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, command, vscode-extensions

I'm developing an extension for Visual Studio Code (in Visual Studio Code), and I want to add one more button to the pop-up menu when a user clicks `ctrl + right click`. A visual representation of what I'm trying to convey is shown below:
[image]

However, I'm not sure how to do this, and I couldn't find documentation about it either.

Comment: You mean, you wannt to add one more button to this menu, right?

Comment: Yup that's what I mean @Dimava

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to customize context menu in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46714353/how-to-customize-context-menu-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement a menu contribution. You can find related docs at https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.menus. In your extension manifest (package.json), fill in the appropriate config in `contributes` > `menus`. The screenshot you've shown is of the `editor/context` menu. You register the menu item contribution with a corresponding command that clicking the menu item will call, and then you implement the command in the same way you'd implement any other command contribution (see also https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.commands).

If you want to see an example of an extension that contributes a menu, see https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/source-control-sample.