# VS Code extension context menu item with checkmark/tick

Tags: vscode-extensions

Is it possible to add boolean options to a context menu in my VS Code extension?

See the below screenshot of the built in context menu that appears when I right click the activity bar, some of the items have a tick in the margin on the left, how can I achieve the same when I add items to the menu?

[image: activity bar context menu]

Answer (score 1):

Just mentioning because it need upvotes: [Add ability for extensions to have "checked" commands](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/109306).

So [How to add toggle menu to 'view/title' with VSCode extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65905635/how-to-add-toggle-menu-to-view-title-with-vscode-extension/65909427#65909427) is probably your only workaround.